# No me muestra el título del producto en la página del mismo. WOOCOMMERCE WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo un problema, en la página de cada producto no me muestra el título, he mirado ya varias fórmulas y nada... Por favor a ver si me podéis ayudar... Adjunto imagen.

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de bienvenida y leer la sección ¿Cómo preguntar?. Por favor agrega una descripción del problema, un ejemplo de valores de entrada, la salida que esperas obtener y la salida que estas obteniendo

Comment: Diria que si que sale el título ese, pero esta debajo de algo que tapa todo, y que es de color blanco. Prueba con el boton derecho sobre ese espacio, y cuando aparezca el menú contextual selecciona "Inspeccionar" para que te abra las herramientas de depuracion de tu navegador.  Allí podras ver el código que aparece en ese punto y de que se trata, y podras jugar con el eliminandolo y ver que hay debajo, donde seguramente aparecerá el titulo. Y si no me equivoco será el tamaño de las fotos en si.

Comment: Hola, he comprobado y no hay título/letras en blanco ...

Comment: @masterguru , necesito que me ayudes ... Las letras no están en color blanco

Comment: eso tiene url publica?  asi lo puedo ver directamente, porque me parece que no sabes usar la depuracion

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No sé cómo explicarlo de diferente manera... En la página del producto no aparece el título, ,( se ve en la foto adjunta ), necesito urgente una solución por favor. Gracias

Comment: ¿Porque no aparece correctamente la primera letra, lo que parece una N, arriba del todo?  Eso es lo que me hace sospechar que o bien la foto esta encima de eso, o bien hay como un cuadrado blanco que se superpone encima. Por eso te decia que lo miraras con el "Inspeccionar". A menos que con tu afan de ocultar cualquier dato lo hayas hecho tu. Entonces nada, me estaré equivocando.

Comment: Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] del sitio para entender como funcionamos aquí y para conseguir la mejor ayuda posible.  Tal como está formulada tu pregunta es practicamente imposible ayudarte pues carece de un [example] y tan solo contiene una foto, y por mucho que intentemos adivinarlo (como yo hasta ahora) nos va a ser muy dificil querer perder el tiempo si tu no pones de tu parte en explicarlo bien mostrandonos algo más que una imagen, como por ejemplo, podria ser el código de esa página.

Comment: @masterguru lo que dices que ves es el logo ( lo he borrado un poco por privacidad ), no doy con la solución... 

Comment: Vale, eso me confundia, y por eso pense que habia algo encima de algo. Bueno, pues no te queda otra que ir al tema que estes usando y buscar el título (ya sea en su propio codigo o bien via el admin) o empezar a mirar dentro de tu wp donde narices se selecciona si aparece o no aparece. Como te he dicho en mi previo mensaje, desde aqui ya no podemos hacer mas, solo tu tienes tu fuente y lo puedes encontrar. Suerte!

Comment: Es decir, ¿si cambias el tema temporalmente aparece el título? Si es así ya estas acotando el problema al html del tema. Si no entonces el problema es mas gordo y será del php supongo o de la configuracion general del wp+wo